# Is there a better way to compute column based on condition

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have this data

```
DAY COST    INCOME  COMMISSION1 COMMISSION2
0   10000               0.75    0.85
1             3000      0.75    0.85
2             2000      0.75    0.85
3             3000      0.75    0.85
4             3000      0.75    0.85
5             1000      0.75    0.85
6             2500      0.75    0.85
7             1300      0.75    0.85
8             3000      0.75    0.85
9             2000      0.75    0.85
10            2500      0.75    0.85
```

Where I have to compute value based on whether the product has been paid off or not. Use commission1 if not paid off , and use commission2 if paid off. I have this sample code.

```
df['INCOME'].iloc[0] = -df['COST'].iloc[0]
df['VALUE1'] =df['INCOME']*df['COMMISSION1']
df['VALUE2'] =df['INCOME']*df['COMMISSION2']
pay_out_index = df['INCOME'].cumsum().searchsorted(0)
df['VALUE'] = np.where(df.index<pay_out_index,df['VALUE1'],df['VALUE2'] )
del df['VALUE1']
del df['VALUE2']
```

But is feel that is not appropriate because I have to do so many computations with the value and I don't want to repeat the process twice. is there a better way such that I do not have to compute value2.

Thanks in advance

Comment: How do you know if a row has been paid off?

Comment: sorry i edited the code... if the 10000 is paid off

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's try using np.where but on rows where INCOME is has not yet reached 10,000:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

df = pd.DataFrame({'DAY': {0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3, 4: 4, 5: 5, 6: 6, 7: 7,
                           8: 8, 9: 9, 10: 10},
                   'Cost': {0: 10000, 1: None, 2: None, 3: None, 4: None,
                            5: None, 6: None, 7: None, 8: None, 9: None},
                   'INCOME': {0: None, 1: 3000, 2: 2000, 3: 3000, 4: 3000,
                              5: 1000, 6: 2500, 7: 1300, 8: 3000, 9: 2000,
                              10: 2500},
                   'COMMISSION1': {0: 0.75, 1: 0.75, 2: 0.75, 3: 0.75, 4: 0.75,
                                   5: 0.75, 6: 0.75, 7: 0.75, 8: 0.75, 9: 0.75,
                                   10: 0.75},
                   'COMMISSION2': {0: 0.85, 1: 0.85, 2: 0.85, 3: 0.85, 4: 0.85,
                                   5: 0.85, 6: 0.85, 7: 0.85, 8: 0.85, 9: 0.85,
                                   10: 0.85}})

df['VALUE'] = np.where(df['INCOME'].cumsum().lt(10_000),
                       df['INCOME'] * df['COMMISSION1'],
                       df['INCOME'] * df['COMMISSION2'])

print(df)
```

`df`:

```
    DAY     Cost  INCOME  COMMISSION1  COMMISSION2   VALUE
0     0  10000.0     NaN         0.75         0.85     NaN
1     1      NaN  3000.0         0.75         0.85  2250.0
2     2      NaN  2000.0         0.75         0.85  1500.0
3     3      NaN  3000.0         0.75         0.85  2250.0
4     4      NaN  3000.0         0.75         0.85  2550.0
5     5      NaN  1000.0         0.75         0.85   850.0
6     6      NaN  2500.0         0.75         0.85  2125.0
7     7      NaN  1300.0         0.75         0.85  1105.0
8     8      NaN  3000.0         0.75         0.85  2550.0
9     9      NaN  2000.0         0.75         0.85  1700.0
10   10      NaN  2500.0         0.75         0.85  2125.0
```

Comment: I dont think thats correct. There are 5 columns day, cost, income, comm1,comm2. By day 4 , the 10000 has been paid off, the 5 days should have value based on comm2

Comment: Try now. It was hard to understand the column format with the blank spaces.

Comment: Thanks.. I need to learn how to add table format data :-) to SO

Comment: Including the output from `df.to_dict()` is usually the way to go since it can be copied and turned into a dataframe without modification.